# Pre Fill Symfony Form Text Field with Data From the Database

Tags: php, symfony

How can I pre fill a text field in symfony with data from the database. I have a field in the host table called hostFee and when I create the form I want that data to pre fill this text field.

I am creating a form for new BookingSpecsType()...

Here is my form builder element.

```
$builder->add('hostFee', 'text', array(
        'required'=>false,
        'error_bubbling'=>true,
        'label'=>'Do you charge a hosting fee?',
        'data' => '??????? (How do I fill this text field dynamically with the Host table hostFee column data) ?????',
        'attr'=>array(
            'placeholder'=>'If yes, enter dollar amount $0.00',
            'class'=>'form-control'
        )
    ));
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can see te code generated for the crud command and see how it works. I guess you want to edit an entity?

Comment: Text inputs have a value attribute, not data.  The form system will set the value attribute automatically from the data object you passed in when creating the form.  The documentation has examples of how to get started.

Comment: This worked for me: $form->get('hostFee')->setData($host->getHostFee());

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission) provide many examples.

When you use `$this->createForm` in your Controller action, the second parameter, allow you to hydrate the form with an object.

**For example:**

```
public function editAction()
{
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('User')->find(1); // YOUR OBJECT RETRIEVED FROM THE DB FOR EXAMPLE
        $form = $this->createForm(new EditType(), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_edit'),
        ));

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeAccountBundle:Account:edit.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define manally the data. If you just init the form from an hydrated entity, then all data are init into all fields.